# Can Keycloak protect port 3000 from an app that listens to 3003?

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, port, keycloak

I want to use Keycloak to secure my node.js application (There are two parts of my app one on port 3003 and the other on 3000). My application is running on port 3003. But I want to secure a page which is running on 3000. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To protect an open interface/port in your application, you need a gateway (reverse proxy). Keycloak is not a gateway but an Authorization server. Of course, Keycloak can do the authentication and authorization for the users accessing port 3000 (e. g. issue a token), but not the access policy enforcement (validate the token and grant/deny access).

There are several gateway/reverse proxies on the market. However, it depends on the service running on port 3000 which fits best. E. g. for an HTTP based API you could use Kong (which is available as an Open Source community edition).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have to connect Keycloak to both of them. Try doing it for one of them and communicate in a different way.